# I tried to test my code written in Go but I keep getting this error and I don't know why

Tags: go, compiler-errors, trace

Firstly I'm writing a package myself named **trace** and it has two files, to run the entire package I write to the terminal:

```
go test -cover
```

But this error comes out:

```
--- FAIL: TestNew (0.00s)
    tracer_test.go:19: We haven't written our test yet
FAIL
coverage: 100.0% of statements
exit status 1
FAIL    gizmo/go/src/trace      0.172s
```

Here is the code of the two files in the trace package:
The first one, tracer.go

```
package trace

import (
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

//Tracer is the interface that describes an object capable of tracing events throughout code

type Tracer interface {
    Trace(...interface{})
}


type tracer struct {
    out io.Writer
}

func (t *tracer) Trace(a ...interface{}){
    fmt.Fprint(t.out, a...)
    fmt.Fprintln(t.out)
}

func New(w io.Writer) Tracer {
    return &tracer{out: w}
}
```

The second one, tracer_test.go

```
package trace

import (
    "testing"
    "bytes"
)

func TestNew(t *testing.T) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    tracer := New(&buf)
    if tracer == nil {
        t.Error("Return from New should not be nil")
    } else {
        tracer.Trace("Hello trace package.")
        if buf.String() != "Hello trace package.\n" {
            t.Errorf("Trace should not write '%s'.", buf.String())
        }
    }
    t.Error("We haven't written our test yet")
}
```

I'd really like someone to help me with this, I'm stuck. **(I don't want the test to fail but to pass).**

Comment: You are always calling `t.Error`. This will fail the test as expected.

Comment: ok thanks man, but the problem is that it prints FAIL in the terminal as you can see instead of PASS

Comment: Are you asking why your test fails when you call `t.Error`? Perhaps you expect go cover to not produce FAIL even if the tests fail?

Comment: Exactly @PaulHankin i didn't expect go cover to produce FAIl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go cover` runs tests and reports their success, in addition to producing coverage information. It seems like your options are to either ignore the `FAIL` message from the failing test, or remove the `t.Error` line that's causing the failure.

A more complicated solution would be to add a flag (or build tag) that conditionally fails the incomplete test based on its value. Then you can set the flag when running `go cover`. But personally I wouldn't bother with anything so complicated.

Comment: You need to remove the `t.Error("We haven't written our test yet")` in order to make the test PASS
Thanks @PaulHankin